# Open cv gives a blank window with my USB camera

Tags: opencv

I was using my acer crystal eye camera until now. It was giving me the exact output as I need but when I moved into using my Logitech camera it gives me just a black window.

Nothing is wrong with my Logitech camera I am using it for skyping and even I tried the onlinemirror as well.

Can anybody help me. there were lot of solutions for this issue but nothing helped me.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <cv.h>
  #include <highgui.h>

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  CvCapture *video = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);

     IplImage * img = NULL

     if(!cvGrabFrame(video)){
     printf("could not grab a frame\n");
     exit(0);
     }

     cvNamedWindow("original_image",0);

     while(1){
        img = cvQueryFrame(video);
        cvShowImage("original_image",img);
        if (cvWaitKey(0)==27){
        break;
        }

     cvReleaseImage(&img);

     cvReleaseCapture(&video);

     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
     }
```

Comment: Whenever possible; don't use the c interface of openCV. Do all of us a favour and switch to the c++ version!

Comment: I will keep that in mind. This case I was specifically driven to use C.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use if `(cvWaitKey(30)==27)` works instead of if `(cvWaitKey(0)==27)`

The highgui needs some time to update the frame.

Comment: But my code works and gives me results with my Acer crystal eye camera.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your usb camera has index 1?

```
CvCapture *video = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
```

You could try to disable your acer webcam in the Device Manager (if you are using windows) and then replace the above line with:

```
CvCapture *video = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);
```

This way, you make sure you only have 1 camera enabled(the usb camera), and by using CV_CAP_ANY you make sure that that one cam is used. If this still gives you a black/blank screen, you know something else is wrong.

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? And did you install the drivers for the usb cam? In some cases, a webcam is recognized by windows (even without the proper drivers) but does not work in OpenCV

Comment: If you try to use the index of 1 (and there is no camera with that number) opencv should give an error, not just a blank screen.

Comment: Ok, so that couldn't be the problem to begin with ;) Your suggestion of increasing the waiting time could solve the problem indeed.

Comment: version is 2.0. I know it is not the latest one but I couldn't configure any of the other versions. Drivers were automatically installed. And no error was there just a black screen

Comment: Most webcams should work, as they support standard USB drivers. Some cameras give problems with linux, but i've not seen a 'standard' logitech camera fail with opencv due to drivers.